# Match price with multiple comma

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match values having multiple comma in them. I'm able to match values with only 1 comma.  regex: `(\$\d+\,\d+)`  Example Value: `$567,76`  but i need to match this value `$567,76,87` but this regex is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this pattern, maybe it could help.

```
^\$\d+(,\d+)*$
```

This will match on

```
$567
$567,76
$567,76,87
```

but not

```
$567,76,87,
```

- [Regex Demo (*click on `.Net` button*)](http://fiddle.re/0n1j6)

Comment: Thanks, but what if i have this kind of value `$1,095.00`?

Comment: try this, `^\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?$` and [here's the demo](http://fiddle.re/fn2h6)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the value using `double.Parse(currency, NumberStyles.Currency)` instead of using a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
^\$\d+(,\d+)+$
```

Some random matches;

```
$1622,40,749
$37,5844
```

---

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^\$\d+(,\d+)+$");

string[] partNumbers = { "$567,76", "$567,76,87", "$567,76,87," };
foreach (var i in partNumbers)
{
       Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} a valid part number.", i, r.IsMatch(i) ? "is" : "is not");
}
```

---

```
$567,76 is a valid part number.
$567,76,87 is a valid part number.
$567,76,87, is not a valid part number.
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/vKxCgC).